# How do I clean my avocado oil intermediate bulk container so I can store water in it?

Tags: water, reuse

I have two 275 gallon (1040 liter) [IBC totes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_bulk_container) that used to hold avacado oil in one, and canola oil in the other.  I want to use it for emergency drinking water.  What is the best way to clean it and store potable water in it?

Comment: Wash with detergent, rinse, add baking soda & fill with hot water (which will be a challenge at 275 Gallons), agitate (likewise) let sit for a day or more, rinse, repeat baking soda & water until no trace of oil/odor remains. Or get containers that are not pre-contaminated by oils if you want to store water.

Comment: Agitate... well put them on a trailer and do a few miles on rough roads...

Comment: Keeping in mind that 275 gal. is over a tonne of water...

Comment: People forget that water is so heavy, 2294 lbs to be more exact, though it wouldn't be anywhere near full during the cleaning. I would also throw into the container a scrubbing pad or a wash rag or two to provide some physical scrubbing action while Dukes of Hazzard'ing

Answer (score 1):

Commercial IBC washers use high pressure water jets, so  attack thje inner surface with a pressure washer, once with detergent, and then once with water to rinse it out.

this task may be easier with the container laying on its side